# how to assign multiple field into a variable?

Tags: awk

i would like to convert the data.txt file into the following output using awk 1liner

cat data.txt

> - personA neta netb netc
> - personB meta metb metc metd

....

output:

- personA has {neta netb netc} items in his bag
- personB has {meta metb metc metd} items in his bag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a good use for subtr() and index().

```
awk '{print $1FS"has {"substr($0,index($0,$2))"} itmes in his bag."}' data.txt
```

#### output:

> personA has {neta netb netc} itmes in his bag.
>
> personB has {meta metb metc metd} itmes in his bag.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{$1=$1" has";$2="{"$2;print $0"} items in his bag"}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while read line; do
  set -- $line
  person=$1
  shift
  printf "%s has {$s} items in his bag" "$person" "$*"
done < data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
awk '{ items=""; 
       for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {items=items" "$i}; 
       gsub(/^[ ]/, "", items);
       print $1" has {"items"} items in his bag" }' data.txt
```